# GridLayout in Kotlin?

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, kotlin, grid-layout

I am trying to get a 2x6 (WxH) GridLayout in my Kotlin Android application. I have my xml and fragment / adapter set up for a RecyclerView but am a bit at a loss for as how to apply a GridLayout to this.

How can I get my items (listview_row_enrollments.xml) to show in a grid instead of just a horizontal list?

EnrollmentFragment.kt

```
class EnrollmentsFragment : Fragment() {

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var mParam1: String? = null
    private var mParam2: String? = null

    private var mListener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (arguments != null) {
            mParam1 = arguments.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            mParam2 = arguments.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        var view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_enrollments, container, false)
        loadView(view)
        return view
    }

    fun loadView(view: View) {
        var recyclerView: RecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.adapter = EnrollmentsAdapter()
    }

//    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
//        super.onAttach(context)
//        if (context is OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
//            mListener = context
//        } else {
//            throw RuntimeException(context!!.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener")
//        }
//    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        mListener = null
    }

    interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        fun onFragmentInteraction(uri: Uri)
    }

    companion object {

        private val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
        private val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

        fun newInstance(): EnrollmentsFragment {
            val fragment = EnrollmentsFragment()
            val args = Bundle()
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }
}// Required empty public constructor
```

EnrollmentsAdapter.kt:

```
class EnrollmentsAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<EnrollmentsAdapter.EnrollmentsViewHolder>() {
    private val items: List<String>

    init {
        this.items = Arrays.asList("Breaches", "Data Leaks", "Hacker Chatter", "Services Monitored", "xxx", "xxx")
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): EnrollmentsViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.listview_row_enrollments, parent, false)

//        view.titleTextView.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(view.context.assets, "fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf")
//        view.countTextView.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(view.context.assets, "fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf")
//        view.subtextTextView.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(view.context.assets, "fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf")
//        view.updatedTextView.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(view.context.assets, "fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf")

        return EnrollmentsViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: EnrollmentsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 6
    }

    fun getItem(position: Int): String {
        return items[position]
    }

    class EnrollmentsViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bind(value: String) {
//            itemView.titleTextView.text = value
        }

    }

}
```

FragmentEnrollments.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="xxx.xxx.EnrollmentsFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:background="@color/kLightGray"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

listview_row_enrollments.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What my view looks like now:
[image]

Comment: Please check Recyclerview with Gridlayoutmanager for this https://www.android4dev.com/how-to-integrate-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-android/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) instead.

Replace:

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
```

With:

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `recyclerview.layoutManager` from `LinearLayoutManager` to a `GridLayoutManger` [GridLayoutManager doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

1/-in the main_activity.xml Replace your

```
recyclerview.layoutManager from LinearLayoutManager to a GridLayoutManger
```

2-/then in the MainActivity.kt

```
add recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
```

worked for me after long search